# HTML Linter in PHP - Is there some library for HTML Validation&Hint inside an input textarea?

Tags: php, html, linter

I have in my page a textarea input box in which users can put some html code. I would like to provide them of some hints in case their html is not syntactically correct. For example a red circle in correspondence of the incriminated row, a tooltip showing a message, or just another color for the not closed tag.
Searching on the internet I found some useful tools, but most of them are for nodejs, like this one http://htmlhint.com/ , which would be exactly what I want if I could use it on my page.

Answer (score 1):

You can use ace editor (https://ace.c9.io/) or codemirror (https://codemirror.net/) textarea replacements to accomplish what you want. htmlhint also uses ace editor.